# Can I find some dump files of Oracle Sample Schemas? I am trying to install OE schema

Tags: oracle

Installing OE schema from `$ORACLE_HOME/demo/schema/order_entry` is giving me problems.

Installing from [Sample Models and Scripts](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/developer-tools/datamodeler/sample-models-scripts-224531.html) may result in a schema without the data.

Installing from [Github: db-sample-schemas](https://github.com/oracle/db-sample-schemas) is one hell of a task.

Can I get a simple `.dmp` dump file produced from `exp` or `expdp` for easier importing?

Comment: Why is installing from the GitHub files so difficult - did you look at the readme file? And what problems are you getting from the demo folder? Did you [follow the instructions](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/COMSC/installation.htm)?

Answer (score 0):

How about creating the famous SCOTT/tiger schema?

Go into $ORACLE_HOME/rdbms/admin and connect as the SYS user.  Then run utlsampl.sql.  It will create a schema called SCOTT with password tiger.  This has some sample tables like DEPT and EMP.